# When to call activateSession() on WCSession object

Tags: swift, lifecycle, watchos-2, wcsession

I wonder at what point one would call activateSession() on a WCSession object on the watch and on the iOS device.

In the documentation it says:

*Always assign a delegate and activate your session before calling any session-related methods. The session must be configured and activated before sending messages or obtaining information about the state of the connection.*

At first thought I put my code to initialise the session:

```
 if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
```

in **viewDidLoad** on the iOS device and in **willActivate** on the watch side.

*It works...* but I don't think it's a good solution.
I'm not too familiar with the app-lifecycle yet but as far as I understand those are called every time the app's are opened.

Does that result in a "reconnect" every time one of the apps is opened?

Where would be a good place to place that code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you put the `WCSession` code in `viewDidLoad` and `willActivate` it is not only called when the app is opened but every time the view controller that contains the code is shown. So that is not an ideal place.

The best place to put this code is in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in your app's `AppDelegate` and in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` in your watch extensions's `ExtensionDelegate`

You can put all the session handling into a singleton class, as suggested in this great [tutorial](http://natashatherobot.com/watchconnectivity-application-context/) by [@NatashaTheRobot](https://twitter.com/natashatherobot).

That way the session is only created once for the time the app in being held in memory.

**EDIT**

As [ccjensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386521/ccjensen) pointed out in his comment, if you are using the connection for a **Complication**, **Notification** or **Glance** update you have to activate the session in the ExtensionDelegate's `init` method. `applicationDidFinishLaunching` will not be called in those cases.

Comment: actually the ExtensionDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching is only called when the WatchKit app is being launched. It will not get called when the extension is being launched for a complication, notification or glance update. The ExtensionDelegate's init method is a better place as it will be called in all these other situations.

Comment: Oh, yes you are totally right! Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't thinking that far. I updated my answer.